# C# Visual Studio - Can you create a notification / message box that pops up independently from your program and won't stop it from closing completely?

Tags: c#, notifications

Is it possible to create a message box or something of the sort that will remain on the screen even though the main application fully closed?

I have a method that automatically closes my program when it detects that there is an update available. I want to notify the users why the application closed and that they need to restart it. The program is shared on a server and used by multiple people simultaneously, so in order to update it I need to make sure it isn't locked open or being used by another person but I want a notification to remain on their screen letting them know what happened.

My current workaround would be to start another application that tells them what happened but it would be cool if there was a better alternative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting a second Process is the only way to do this: For the program to terminate, nothing within it can be left running, such as any dialog boxes.

Also, wouldn't it be better UX to inform the user there is an update and they need to restart to the program without suddenly terminating the program without warning?

Ideally, you wouldn't have multiple users running from the same executable, but in order to work around the file locking, have the program make a dummy file on launch, and remove that dummy file when closing - The update runs once there are no dummy files present. This is assuming the update is handled by a separate program.

If I absolutely had to implement that sort of functionality, something like this in `Program.cs`

```
static void Main() {
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    CreateDummyFile();
    Application.Run(new Form1());
    DeleteDummyFile();
}

static void CreateDummyFile() {
    String fileName = Application.StartupPath + @"\" + Environment.MachineName + ".tmp";
    using (FileStream fs = File.Create(fileName)) { }
}

static void DeleteDummyFile() {
    String fileName = Application.StartupPath + @"\" + Environment.MachineName + ".tmp";
    File.Delete(fileName);
}
```

Include the `System.IO` namespace - This assumes you are using WinForms

Comment: Great input, thank you. I'm really pretty new to the whole thing in general, how would one go about making said dummy file on launch and reliably remove itself?

Comment: I can create a new thread if you feel it's more appropriate or you don't have time to answer.

Comment: There's an example of how one would go about doing that, but I feel that there's base architectural issues at work here that should be resolved - Why are all your users running from a single network-shared executable? Why are updates being applied immediately, and how are you handling work in progress when they are? I've done similar work in the past and I preferred to copy the exe locally, and check for an update (and launch an update program) when the program is started.

Comment: The application is small and work in progress being an issue is next to non-existent. Updates aren't being applied immediately per say but people leave applications running on their machines all night. They're also running from a single shared location so I can manage it without user hassle, users can't really install things in a conventional manner either because my department doesn't have permissions for it  and users can't really be relied upon to do things themselves. But you're right, I should probably rethink my approach to the whole thing in general.

Comment: Having worked under similar limitations, copying the executable to the user's desktop and having it check for an updated version on launch, and running an update application (that can be on the network share) that copies the updated exe into place saves on a lot of issues.